# Django filter with two hops over ForeignKeys

Tags: python, django, django-models

In Django, is it possible to do something like this?

`foo = Account.objects.filter(owner__address__zipcode='94704').get()`

with the following premises:

- Account has an `Owner` foreign key to an Owner model.
- Owner has an `Address` foreign key to an Address model.
- Address has a `zipcode` char field.

Comment: did you try this? What is not working ? `.get()` might throw an error if that filter criteria does not return results. You might want to try `.first()`

Comment: yes. that was it. thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, this is supported in Django ORM.

The feature is [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).